# how to show 10 data when I am scrolling down Its just show next 10 data in react js?

Tags: reactjs

When I am using scroll down so that time our function "fetchMoreData"?
I want to scroll down that time my function is called

```js
    const fetchMoreData = () =>{
        console.log("pulkit")
    }      

         <InfiniteScroll
              dataLength={25}
              next={fetchMoreData}
              hasMore={true}
              loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}>
          <Grid container spacing={4} sx={{ marginTop: '1rem' }}>
            {simulationList.map((item, i) => (
              <Grid
                item
                xs={3}
                key={item?._id}
              >
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
         </InfiniteScroll>
```

Comment: when I am using scroll down our function fetchMoreData is not calling .

Comment: you need is a pagination instead of infinite scroll?

Comment: I have lots of records inside map method  {simulationList.map((item, i) => (
              <Grid
                item
                xs={3}
                key={item?._id}
              >
              </Grid>
            ))}

Comment: I want to pagination but in the current time my function is not calling and I am using first time infinite scroll and I want to pagination when i am scrolling down.

Comment: try changing dataLength ={10} ..I hope this is what you want. dataLength is the amount of length that needs to be displayed.

Comment: next={fetchMoreData} this is not working ?

Comment: your dataLength should be less than the total length of the data.Let me know if it's not working even after reducing the value.The function won't be called if you made this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the different scroll libraries of functions to scroll in react.
for my code, i have been using this "react-scroll-wheel-handler" which allows me to display only the required number of items on the screen and even allows me to change the setting in the UI where i can change the number of results in the output table.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-wheel-handler
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to recreate your scenario.It's from react-infinite-scroll-component
example.. Try this out
[Sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/thirsty-jepsen-3r50fi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any lib you can do using it to react `onScroll` event pls find the working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-lichterman-1nl4gu?file=/src/index.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const style = {
  height: 30,
  border: "1px solid green",
  margin: 6,
  padding: 8
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: Array.from({ length: 20 })
  };



  fetchMoreData = () => {
    console.log("pulkit");
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat(Array.from({ length: 20 }))
      });
    }, 1500);
  };

  onHandleScroll = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    if (e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop === e.target.clientHeight) {
      this.fetchMoreData()
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onScroll={this.onHandleScroll} style={{
        overflow: "scroll", height: '800px'
      }}>
        <h1>demo: react-infinite-scroll-component</h1>
        <hr />
        {this.state.items.map((i, index) => (
          <div style={style} key={index}>
            div - #{index}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```